# How to process Hangfire BackgroudJobs Singly instead of in Parallel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, background-process, hangfire

I have a Hangfire `BackgroundJob.Enque()` method, where all my business logic is written.

It works fine with one request processing at a time, but multiple requests all start together, creating deadlock issues.

I want requests to execute singly; how can I achieve this, please?

Comment: Hey Jayesh, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

To disable concurrent execution of the same job type running on different workers you should decorate your method with `[DisableConcurrentExecution]`attribute.

Comment: Mikel - is there a link to any online documentation for this? Could you also post a link if there is, please? Just to add to Mikel's post, the only reference I found to the setting in the online documentation, was this: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/throttling.html. Hangfire's documentation is pretty poor, to be honest; the search doesn't appear to work (unless it's using some script on a server that's disallowed by our firewall), and, obviously, detail on the minutiae is missing.

Comment: @Paul You have posted the exact doc source, so I cannot provide anything else. In case of poor doc I advice to take a look at source code what I usually do in addition to docs.